# Trouble using UIImageView to show animations

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview

I am an iOS beginner working through the [Pragmatic iOS book](http://pragprog.com/book/adios/ios-sdk-development), and am having trouble with one of the chapter end "challenges" where I am to show slideshow of images in the `UIImageView` in my nib file.

I have a model class `Recipe.h`, as well as a `ViewController` and the standard `AppDelegate.h` files.  Everything that is all wired up correctly, and if I were to show only **one** image in my `UIImageView` via `self.imageView.image = self.recipe.image`, everything works correctly.  However, if I were to do the following and attempt to show using `animnationImages`, no images show up:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //...some code here

    if(self.recipe.imageArray){
        self.imageView.animationDuration = 2;
        self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
        self.imageView.animationImages = self.recipe.imageArray;
        NSLog(@"%@", self.imageView.animationImages);
    }
}
```

My NSLog outputs the `UIImage: 0x7520d60, UIImage: 0x7522390`, which I take it that `self.imageView.animationImages` has the images located in memory.  However, why are the pictures not showing up?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `[self.imageView startAnimating];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[self.view startAnimating];
```